# how go to next page in yii2 from listview?

Tags: php, listview, yii2

I am having this problem on yii2 please how do i move from one page to another in listview that's all nothing i try seems to be working. i want when the listview is clicked it takes you to another page and carries the datas of the Colon that is click. to the next page

this is the index.php

```
<?php

use yii\widgets\ListView;
use yii\data\ArrayDataProvider;
use app\models\MyProfile;
use app\models\LikeDiscussion;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use common\models\Topic;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use frontend\assets\AppAsset;

$this->title = 'My Yii Application';
?>
           <?php

         $query = Topic::find()->all();
            $dataArr = array();
          foreach ($query as $detail) {
            $dataArr[] = array(
                'topic_id' => $detail->topic_id,
                'topic' => $detail->topic,
                'created' => $detail->created,
                'creator' => $detail->creator,
                 'views' => $detail->views
            );
          }

          $dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
                'allModels' => $dataArr,
                'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 10,
                ],
                'sort' => [
                    'attributes' => ['views'=>SORT_ASC]
                ],
            ]);
?>  
<?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'countries']) ?>
         <?=  ListView::widget([
             'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
             'itemOptions' => ['class' => 'comment-item'],
             'itemView' => 'indexadapter',

        ]);
            ?>
<?php Pjax::end() ?>
<div class="hr">
</div>
```

indexadapter

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\HtmlPurifier;

//var_dump($model);exit;
?>


    <div class="gravatar" >
                <img src="images/gravatar.png" alt="" >
            </div>
            <h5><?php echo $model['topic_id'];
            ?>
            </h5>
            <p>
            <h5>
            <span class="commentdate">
                <?php echo $model['created']. "by" .$model['creator']; ?>
            </span>
            </h5>
        </p>
            <hr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 <?= Html::a(Html::encode($model->topic_id), ['view', 'id' => $model->id]); ?>
```

Comment: this was helpful but it is direction me to another url . <?= Html::a(Html::encode('page2'), ['index.php?r=site%2Fblog', 'id' => $model['topic_id']]); ?> instead of  'index.php?r=site%2Fblog  the url is index.php?r=site%2Findex.php%3Fr%3Dsite%252Fblog&id=1